# Selecting image on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to write code to select an image from the photo library on an iPad.  The code that I'm using is below (taken from Apple's website), but it keeps giving me an error saying that `On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController`.  I've tried changing this line: `UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];` to use a UIPopoverController, but obviously I'm doing something wrong because its not working.

```
- (BOOL) selectImage: (UIViewController*) controller
       usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                       UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;

    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    // Displays saved pictures and movies, if both are available, from the
    // Camera Roll album.
    mediaUI.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];

    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = NO;

    mediaUI.delegate = delegate;

    [controller presentModalViewController: mediaUI animated: YES];
    return YES; }
```

The Apple Developer page also says: "On iPad, you can alternatively present the browser interface using a popover as described in initWithContentViewController: and “Presenting and Dismissing the Popover” in UIPopoverController Class Reference."  I've read it but I still can't get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
// create an image picker controller 
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;

// present it in a popover
self.popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController] autorelease];
self.popoverController.delegate = self;
// I was presenting the popover from a button, but you would set the rect to whatever is appropriate for your app
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare an ivar such as:

```
UIPopoverController *imagePopover;
```

Then:

```
imagePopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:mediaUI];
[imagePopover setDelegate:self];

[imagePopover presentPopoverFromRect:someRect
                              inView:someView
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                           animated:YES];
```

in place of

```
[controller presentModal...];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.delegate = self;

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 400.0) 
                         inView:self.view
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                       animated:YES];
```

refer below link

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPad_Camera_and_UIImagePickerController_Application_%28Xcode_4%29

Answer (score 1):

I went through a lot of pain coming up with  a solution which works on both iPad and iPhone, this is the final code which some of it comes from comments of other people:
the code has some bugs but it's a very good place to start :) 
it covers permissions needed as well as how to manage viewcontrollers popoing up on ipad.

requires following imports :

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
```

and add this delegates :

```
UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
```

definitions :

```
__weak IBOutlet UIButton *attachButton;
UIImage *image;
```

button's action :

```
    - (IBAction)doAttach:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select image from" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"From library",@"From camera", nil] ;
    [action showInView:self.view];
  }



#pragma mark - ActionSheet delegates

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if( buttonIndex == 1 ) {
        AVAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", @"You have camera access");
        }
        else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusDenied)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", @"Denied camera access");

            [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
                if(granted){
                    NSLog(@"Granted access to %@", AVMediaTypeVideo);
                } else {
                    [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@“no camera access“
                                                                                   message: @“if you need to use camera in this application go to settings -> appName -> and turn on camera.”
                                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@“ok” style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                                          }];
                    [alert addAction:defaultAction];

                    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];


                    NSLog(@"Not granted access to %@", AVMediaTypeVideo);
                    return ;
                }
            }];
        }
        else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
        {
            [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@“no camera access“
                                                                                   message: @“if you need to use camera in this application go to settings -> appName -> and turn on camera.”
                                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@“ok” style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                                  }];
            [alert addAction:defaultAction];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];


            NSLog(@"%@", @"Restricted, normally won't happen");
        }
        else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", @"Camera access not determined. Ask for permission.");

            [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
                if(granted){
                    NSLog(@"Granted access to %@", AVMediaTypeVideo);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Not granted access to %@", AVMediaTypeVideo);
                    return ;
                }
            }];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@“No camera access“
                                                                           message: @“error accusing camera”
                                                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@“ok” style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                                  }];
            [alert addAction:defaultAction];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];


            return;
            //NSLog(@"%@", @"Camera access unknown error.");
        }

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {


            UIImagePickerController *pickerView =[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
            pickerView.allowsEditing = YES;
            pickerView.delegate = self;
            pickerView.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;


            if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

                [ self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil ];

                pickerView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
                UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = pickerView.popoverPresentationController;
                popPC.sourceView = attachButton;
                popPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
                [self presentViewController:pickerView animated:YES completion:nil];
            } else {
                [self presentModalViewController:pickerView animated:YES ];
            }
        }

    }else if( buttonIndex == 0 ) {

        ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
        switch (status) {
            case ALAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            case ALAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            {
                [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@“no access to library”
                                                                               message: @“if you wish to access photos in this app go to settings -> appName-> and turn on photos .”
                                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@“ok” style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                                      }];
                [alert addAction:defaultAction];

                [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            }
                break;

            default:
            {
                UIImagePickerController *pickerView = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                pickerView.allowsEditing = YES;
                pickerView.delegate = self;

                [pickerView setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];


                if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

                    [ self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil ];

                    pickerView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
                    UIPopoverPresentationController *popup = pickerView.popoverPresentationController;
                    popup.sourceView = attachButton;
                    popup.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
                    [self presentViewController:pickerView animated:YES completion:nil];
                } else {
                    [self presentModalViewController:pickerView animated:YES ];
                }
            }
                break;
        }



    }
}

#pragma mark - PickerDelegates

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];

    UIImage * img = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    image = img;

}
```